# Combinatorics in R

Tags: r, probability, combinatorics

I have 4 items and I can peak 3 of them at random.But how can I calculate in R the total combinations?

I think it might be:

```
sample(4,3)
```

for one sample.But each time to run the sample function and if the results are the same or included in the previous results to be excluded and run it again until all the possible combinations occurs.

But how this can be done in R ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `combn` to get all possible combinations:

```r
combn(4, 3)

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    1    2
[2,]    2    2    3    3
[3,]    3    4    4    4
```

For permutations, you can use, e.g., `gtools::permutations`:

```r
gtools::permutations(4, 3)

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    1    2    3
 [2,]    1    2    4
 [3,]    1    3    2
 [4,]    1    3    4
 [5,]    1    4    2
 [6,]    1    4    3
 [7,]    2    1    3
 [8,]    2    1    4
 [9,]    2    3    1
[10,]    2    3    4
[11,]    2    4    1
[12,]    2    4    3
[13,]    3    1    2
[14,]    3    1    4
[15,]    3    2    1
[16,]    3    2    4
[17,]    3    4    1
[18,]    3    4    2
[19,]    4    1    2
[20,]    4    1    3
[21,]    4    2    1
[22,]    4    2    3
[23,]    4    3    1
[24,]    4    3    2
```

Comment: not like this.This is easy I know it.I want the output of all the possible combinations

Comment: Then use `combn`

Comment: that will do but how can I do it with the sample function

Comment: Do you mean with permutations? I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: like your edit both observe that some combinations are repeated (in different order).Imagine the output of the permutations function as you did but without the  repeated combinations

Comment: Without the repeated combinations it’s the columns of the result of combn